# Android performance - Multiple View.OnClickListener x checking which view called onClick

Tags: android, performance, button, imageview, onclicklistener

I have some `Button` and `ImageView` variables in my Activity, and considering the big picture (device memory, memory leak, performance etc), what is the best option to implement?

Option 1 - Each widget has your own `View.OnClickListener`:

```
buttonA = new Button(this);
buttonB = new Button(this);
buttonC = new Button(this);

buttonA.setOnClickListener(new ListenerA());
buttonB.setOnClickListener(new ListenerB());
buttonC.setOnClickListener(new ListenerC());
```

Option 2 - All widgets share the same `View.OnClickListener`:

```
buttonA = new Button(this);
buttonB = new Button(this);
buttonC = new Button(this);

MyListener mListener = new MyListener();

buttonA.setOnClickListener(mListener);
buttonB.setOnClickListener(mListener);
buttonC.setOnClickListener(mListener);

...

class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == buttonA.getId()){
          // stuff A
        }

        if(v.getId() == buttonB.getId()){
          // stuff B
        }

        if(v.getId() == buttonC.getId()){
          // stuff C
        }
    }
}
```

I can imagine that the first options is faster, because no `if` statement is needed to know which view invoked the call, but the second is better speaking about memory usage?

Comment: Doesn't matter. If there's some shared code, you could go with a shared listener. If there is no code shared I'd use a different listener on each button.

Comment: Sounds like extremely early premature optimization. For the most part it's a matter of style and what action(s) do you want to perform inside the listeners. You don't want a huge onClick() method with confusing (and unrelated) things. Also it depends if you like to have anonymous methods next to where you define those callbacks. Just go with what makes easier to read code and you'll be fine.

Comment: option 3- `button[A|B|C].setOnClickListener(this);` and directly compare `View v` with  `button[A|B|C]`